# Remove a property from list in C#

Tags: c#, list

hi i want to remove a property from list if a condition is true, my code is like below

```cs
foreach (var entry in entries)
{
    var item = list
        .BillingItems
        .Select(x => new {
            OrganizationId   = entry.Organization,
            OrganizationName = entry.Organization,
            Revenue = entry.Revenue
        });
}
```

Revenue// this property need to remove if condition is true

can i remove this withing new blocks

Comment: Just set it to null, Though how do you intend to use an indeterminate anonymous object, why do you need this?

Comment: `Revenue          = !condition ? entry.Revenue : null` to put `null` when `condition` meets

Comment: Make a step back and ask yourself: what would you do with such an object if you could do that **at runtime**? You´ll never know **at compile**-time, if your returned object has the property or not. The whole point of static type-safety is, that you know **at compile-time** which members a given objects has.

Comment: i have issue with binding a list and export as csv, this property comes as header even it doesnt exist so i want to remove this totaly if the my condtion is true. not the value

Comment: You should have two different lists, one for each condition. Don´t put different things into a common list.

Comment: Do you realise you are `Select`ing the same object over and over again? Did you mean `x` instead of `entry` in the `Select`?

Comment: Look, the most rational solution is to use an if then else. yeah you are writing the same code twice, you could use automapper, with 2 concrete classes. Or depending on what you are binding to, you may be able to hide it after the fact, or depending on what library you are using it probably has options

Comment: Can you check the condition just before you write the CSV? If the condition is true, tell the CSV writer to not write that column. Whatever CSV writer you are using should be able to provide this functionality...

Comment: yes.my final source that wirte to csv not include this property but it shows as header and property type as values, excel doen't give such. so i want to remove this property totally from the list

Comment: I suppose you could use an ExpandoObject, but would that work with your csv code?

Comment: depending on your serialization-framework there are attribuites that you can use to ignore properties from reading/writing. You should use those instead of trying to tweek your data.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
foreach (var entry in entries)
{
    List<dynamic> item = new List<dynamic>();
    foreach (var bi in List.BillingItem)
    {
        if (condition)
        {
            item.Add(new { entry.Organization, entry.Revenue });
        } 
        else
        {
            item.Add(new { entry.Organization });
        }
    }
}
```

But, you are not using values from BillingItem and Im not sure if is your approach realy the right one

Answer (score 0):

You can set it to null if condition ?

```
foreach (var entry in entries){
var item = list
    .BillingItems
    .Select(x => new {
        OrganizationId   = entry.Organization,
        OrganizationName = entry.Organization,
        Revenue = (condition) ? entry.Revenue : null
    });
```

}